# Capturar varios datos con php file_get_content y preg_match

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo:

```
// Example by deerme.org
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.powerball.com/pb_home.asp");

if ( preg_match('|<font size="5" color="#000000"><strong>(.*)</strong></font>| ' , $data , $cap ) )
{
    echo $cap[1];
}
```

Funciona bien, lo que hace es buscar en la pagina una cadena y imprimirla en pantalla, pero solo busca una sola vez y yo necesito que busque en toda la pagina e imprima todas las coincidecias que tenga, aver si alguien que esta familiarizado con el preg_match o si conoce alguna otra manera de acerlo se lo agradeceria. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

En vez de `preg_match()` usa `preg_match_all()`. El tercer parámetro (en el siguiente caso es `$cap`) guarda las ocurrencias que encuentra:

```
$expr = '|<font size="5" color="#000000"><strong>(.*)</strong></font>|';
preg_match_all($expre, $data, $cap);
```

Esta es la [página del manual de preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg-match-all).

Comment: E cambiado preg_match por preg_match_all pero cuando ago echo $cap; me devuelve el texto "Array" que me estara faltando?

Comment: El `echo` es para textos (string). Como $cap es un array, para verlo debes usar `print_r($cap);` o `var_dump($cap);`

Comment: Ok ya casi lo tengo, disculpa mi ignorancia estoy aprendiendo, ahora mi problema es que me devuelve esto Array ( [0] => 33 [1] => 42 [2] => 46 [3] => 59 )  como puedo hacer para limpiarlo y que solo me quede el contenido de cada Array que seria 33 42 46 59 gracias por la ayuda

Comment: tienes que recorrer el array con un foreach ejemplo. `foreach ($array as $clave => $valor) {
            echo "A $clave le corresponde $valor ";
        }`

Answer (score -1):

No se puede usar preg_match para parsear HTML,XML, XHTML ni nada de eso. Por lo mismo es una herramienta inútil para hacer web scraping.

En el mejor de los casos vas a matchear una ocurrencia pero, ¿Qué pasa cuando hay dos coincidencias? ¿Cómo sabes si el final de la segunda coincidencia no es el final de la primera?

Ocurre que HTML tiene una gramática libre y regex espera una gramática regular. Son distintas magnitudes de complejidad.

**Respuesta larga**: Ver [la mejor respuesta al respecto que existe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) y es legendaria en Stack Overflow.

> I think the flaw here is that HTML is a Chomsky Type 2 grammar
>   (context free grammar) and RegEx is a Chomsky Type 3 grammar (regular
>   grammar). Since a Type 2 grammar is fundamentally more complex than a
>   Type 3 grammar (see the Chomsky hierarchy), you can't possibly make
>   this work. But many will try, some will claim success and others will
>   find the fault and totally mess you up.

**Respuesta corta**: usar un parser de XML como [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/es/book.simplexml.php), o una herramienta de scraping como [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) o [PHP Html Parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser).